# What is the proper way to access the `data`, `rowData`, and `metadata` props on a custom Griddle component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

What is the proper way to access the `data`, `rowData`, and `metadata` props on a custom Griddle component? Despite seeing the props populated with my data in the react devtools (e.g. url and title for a link I want to build) the console gives me an error of "Unknown props `rowData`, `metadata` on `<DownloadLink>` tag".

I've tried two approaches based on passing a `customComponentMetadata` key/value and the way the documentation shows as per [this](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/225), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960149/griddle-react-passing-additional-props-to-custom-components), and the [documentation](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/customization.html#customColumns).

```
const columnMetaData = [
  // several objects until...,
  {
    customComponent: 'DownloadLink', // which I import from './components/DownloadLink'
    customComponentMetadata: {
      fileDetails: fileDetails // my array with url and title
    }
  }
];
```

My table receives this as props - `<ResultsTable columnMetadata={columnMetadata} tableData={this.state.tableData} /> // tableData is the entire json object I want to display`.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what do you get if you do a console.log(this.props) in your DownloadLink render method/?

Comment: @finalfreq - That's just it. Nothing. The reason seems to be that in Griddle it doesn't seem like you explicitly pass props to a custom grid component in that way. Usually I would do something like `<Parent propsToPass={something} /> <Child props={this.props.propsToPass} />` 

However according to the docs all you (should) have to do is register the component with the columnMetadata prop for the table. NB - every other prop works and I can _see_ but not access the data in the custom component.

Comment: It turns out I was going about this wrong. The customComponent should not have quotes. I made this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aberkow/f2b82cfed572ad21f17053e39b9ddb71) as an example.